# ▾ and ✓ characters not showing up in IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8

Im using ▾ and ✓ characters which are inputted by the user so I chant use their full html value (something like this `&#10003;`).

These are working fine in Chrome, FF and IE9. However in IE8 they are replaced by a square character (see image below).

[image]

Comment: Did you specify a charset in your HTML code? Do you have a jsfiddle?

Comment: IE8 suggests Windows XP and not having a font with those characters in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I want unicode characters on IE8, I use

```
<span class="unicode">unicode characters here</span>
```

and

```
.unicode {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'DejaVu Serif';
    src: url('fonts/DejaVuSerif.eot');
    src:local('DejaVu Serif'), 
        local('DejaVu Serif Book'), 
        url('fonts/DejaVuSerif.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('fonts/DejaVuSerif.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/DejaVuSerif.svg#font') format('svg');
}
```

Where [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org) fonts are public domain fonts that provide a wider range of characters. You can download their .ttf fonts [here](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Download), and convert them to the other types using online tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Wingdings font, but Mozilla and Opera are standard-compiliant. Wingdings is not standard (what a surprise coming from Microsoft) because not mapped to Unicode, and so should never be used on a website.

However, do not despair, most symbols are available in Unicode : check

http://www.alanwood.net/demos/wingdings.html

The symbol you want is number 252 in the list.